# SQL Pivot how for matrix view and multi tables

Tags: sql-server, pivot

**Problem**: I have 2 tables as below and i want to matrix view from them

1. WorkflowStatus  (the number of the status can be defined by users)

> ```
> ID    |   Name  
> ============== 
> 1     |   Draft  
> 2     |   Submitted
> 3     |   Approved
> 4     |   Rejected
> 5     |   Closed
> 6     |   ...
> ```

2. WorkflowMatrix

> ```
> OldStatus     |  NextStatus  
> ==========================  
> 1 (Draft)     |  2 (Submitted)
> 1 (Draft)     |  3 (Approved)
> 2 (Submitted) |  4 (Rejected)
> 2 (Submitted) |  3 (Approved)  
> 4 (Rejected)  |  2 (Submitted)
> 3 (Approved)  |  5 (Closed)
> ```

**Question**: How to use Pivot command in SQL to view the result as below

```
                |  Draft  | Submitted  |  Approved |  Rejected |  Closed
   =========================================================================
    1 Draft     |         |  true      |  true     |           |
    2 Submitted |         |            |  true     |   true    |
    3 Approved  |         |            |           |           |   true
    4 Rejected  |         |  true      |           |           |
    5 Closed    |         |            |           |           |
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

That is a confusing Pivot

```
SELECT id, 
       NAME, 
       Max(CASE WHEN nextstatus = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE '' END) [Draft], 
       Max(CASE WHEN nextstatus = 2 THEN 'True' ELSE '' END) [Submitted], 
       Max(CASE WHEN nextstatus = 3 THEN 'True' ELSE '' END) [Approved], 
       Max(CASE WHEN nextstatus = 4 THEN 'True' ELSE '' END) [Rejected], 
       Max(CASE WHEN nextstatus = 5 THEN 'True' ELSE '' END) [Closed] 
FROM   WorkflowStatus  a 
       LEFT JOIN WorkflowMatrix b 
              ON a.id = b.oldstatus 
GROUP  BY id, 
          NAME 
ORDER  BY id
```

Comment: Thank you. But in WorkflowStatus table the number of status is not fix. It's better if the columns are generated programmatically

Answer (score 1):

```
Pivot version.

SELECT  id,
        name,
        IIF([1] IS NULL, '', 'true') AS [Draft],
        IIF([2] IS NULL, '', 'true') AS [Submitted],
        IIF([3] IS NULL, '', 'true') AS [Approved],
        IIF([4] IS NULL, '', 'true') AS [Rejected],
        IIF([5] IS NULL, '', 'true') AS [Closed]
FROM    WorkflowStatus  a 
        LEFT JOIN WorkflowMatrix b 
              ON a.id = b.oldstatus 
PIVOT (
    MAX(NextStatus)
    FOR NextStatus IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) p
```

Comment: Thank you. But in WorkflowStatus table the number of status is not fix. It's better if the columns are generated programmatically. I don't know how to use pivot

Comment: In that case, I'd use a dynamic query and build the query to look like Prdp's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but I still got problem when using GROUP BY on pivoted table

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(id) 
                from #WorkflowStatus 
                group by id, Name
                order by id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'');
 
set @query = '
WITH Pivoted
AS
(
SELECT OldStatus, '+ @cols +' FROM
         #WorkflowStatus  a
         LEFT JOIN #WorkflowMatrix b 
          ON a.id = b.NextStatus
        PIVOT
        (
            COUNT(NextStatus)
            for NextStatus in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p
)    
SELECT OldStatus,'+@cols+'
FROM Pivoted a
WHERE OldStatus IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY OldStatus,'+ @cols +'
ORDER BY OldStatus ASC
';

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

I hope I could help.
Here is [the SQL](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/539960)